# Doctrine2 Filter Disabled/Invalid Results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a project that i'm currently migrating from pdo/sql to doctrine, but that's not based in any framework (shame).

I need to add many filters to the products entity, so the rows matched by these filters will never output anywhere in the frontend. The filters are for example: products out of stock, products with empty names, no pictures, no description, column "disabled" set to 1, etc...

How could i create this filter? Is there any example?

I dont think it would be a good solution to use findOneBy and add a multiple-index array with all conditions i need in every page. Also sometimes i update these filters and its not cool to update it everywhere the product entity is used in the project.

Comment: please have a look at my answer. i guess doctrine filters is what you are looking for? if anything unclear please comment otherwise accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Doctrine Filters:**

You can i.e. use Doctrine Filters to filter entities with deletedAt property not null ( softdeletable ):

```
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
// ... your configuration
$config->addFilter('soft-deleteable', 'Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter');
```

Please have look at the [source](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/Filter/SoftDeleteableFilter.php) of the SoftDeletableFilter to understand how it works.

More information can be found in the [Filters section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html) of the documentation.

**Furthermore:**

A very easy implementation of filterable repositories can be achieved with [KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors).

Please have a look at [filterable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#filterable).

Uses traits so php >= 5.4 is needed!